# Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined : axios react

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

```
const config = {
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" }
}

let files = this.state.files
let promises = []
files.map((item ,index) => {
   promises.push(axios.put(this.props.deal.authURL[index], item, config))
})
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

My aim is to store all the result of the Axios calls inside promises array. And then use `Promise.all()` function to resolve all at once. Can't figure why the error is there.

Any sort of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: since the code you are showing doesn't contain anything with `protocol` you are probably showing the wrong code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.props.deal.authURL[index]` was returning an undefined url and that was the reason for the random error.

Comment: well, you might as well delete the question itself, or edit it so that it might be helpful for future readers, which I doubt it is in it's current state

Answer (score 1):

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTIONS**

Like already mentioned above, this error is thrown when we send a malformed request or wrong method or any fault in the body/header.
However, if you have checked all of these, and they are all okay, and you are still getting the error, then chances are you are handling the response wrongly.
How to correct it?
It is always a good idea to `console.log(response)` of the request sent, just so we know how to handle the response.

I faced a similar issue today afternoon. After sitting with it for a while,  correcting all the methods/request links and things like that, I was still getting an error, then I realised I was handling the responses wrongly.

So, it is always recommended to `console.log` the response.