# Url is defined but still getting error of Protocol of Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a GET request using axios and getting the error

> Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

This API endpoint was `http://gateway.apps.test-digital.co.za/api/content/movies` and was working fine. We changed the last part of it in the back-end from 'movies' to 'movie' and did the same in the front-end and now it's breaking with the error message aforementioned.

I have had a look at these resources

1. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/632)
2. [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/118)
3. [Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined : axios react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752259/cannot-read-property-protocol-of-undefined-axios-react?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
4. [关于import axios报错Cannot read property ‘protocol’ of undefined](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/import-axios-cannot-read-property-protocol-of-undefined/10239)

And none of them has solved my problem. Reason being, all these issues turned out to be caused by the fact the url passed to the axios GET method were not defined which is not the case in my instance. When I log the url right before dispatching the axios call, it displays the correct url.

If I change, in the front-end, the last part of the end point from 'movie' to 'movies' (from what it actually is in the backend to what it was) I get a `404`, which is expected because the endpoint changed from 'movies' to 'movie', but when I change back to 'movie' (what it actually is in the back-end) I get the error mentioned above.

Here is the code making the request

```
function getMovies() {
  const url = movieContentUrls.getMovieUrl();
  console.log("The url: ", url) //This logs the correct url to where the movies sit
  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('ERROR: ', error.message);
        return null;
    });
}
```

The `getMovieUrl` function is defined in an object like this:

```
getMovieUrl: () => `${moviesApiBaseUrl}/content/movie`
```

And the network tab:

[image]

**Questions**

1. What may be going wrong here?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you open the url in your browser?

Comment: Instead of calling the method and getting the url from there try to put url as string. It might be like url might be getting populated later, mean while service call was made.

Comment: @Gyanendra, I have tried that and I get the same behaviour.  HMR, The url works fine in the browser and not in the code. I am quite certain that this is not a CORS issue btw.

Comment: Are you seeing this error in the browser or in a sort of node test environment?

Comment: @PierreC. I am running the project locally at the moment, and whenever I try load the movies page, I get that error

Comment: Did you check the network calls? Is your api being called in the way it was supposed to? And let us know the error shown in the network tab as well

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay, I have and the API is called the way it is supposed to. I have updated the post with a screen shot of the network tab.

Comment: did you try bundling it and hosting it on your server? then you can negate out the cors issue permanently

Comment: No, I haven't. I am not sure if that would help either, because this seems to not be a CORS issue